# Find distance between two points on Cartesian plane

Tags: triangles

I have a triangle on the Cartesian plane where I know the following:

$$A = (X_1, Y_1)$$

$$B = (X_2, Y_2)$$

$$C = (X_3, Y_3)$$

$$\angle ABC = 90$$

$$\overline{AB} = x$$

$$\overline{AC} = 2x$$

I know A and B but I don't know C's location.

Can I use these parameters to find distance $\overline{BC}$?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Try looking up the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: Use Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: are we using a euclidean metric ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

Since we know the angle $\measuredangle ABC = 90º$, by the **Pythagorean Theorem** we know that $$(\overline{AB})^2 + (\overline{BC})^2 = (\overline{AC})^2$$

$$(\overline{BC})^2 = (\overline{AC})^2 - (\overline{AB})^2$$

$$(\overline{BC})^2 = (2x)^2 - x^2$$

$$(\overline{BC})^2 = 3x^2 \Leftrightarrow \overline{BC} = \sqrt3|x|$$

Without knowing what $x$ means, **we can't find the exact value for** $ \overline{BC}$, but we can find a **general solution** for $\overline{BC}$, where givin any $x$, we know  $\overline{BC}$.